First syzygy is unique up to direct summand
Let $R:=K[x_0,...,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring over a field $K$ and $M$ be finitely generated $R$ module. Let $(m_i)_{i=1,...,k}$ be a generating set for $M$. Then we can define the free module $F_0 := R^k$. Then we have a canonical surjection
$$\pi : F_0 \to M$$
by mapping the $i$-th generator of $F_0$ to $m_i$. Then the first module of syzygies of $M$ is the kernel $\ker (\pi)$. But this module depends on the choice of the generating set. Say $(m'_j)_{j=1,...,k'}$ is another generating set, $F_0'$ and $\pi'_0$ the respective constructions.
I have seen that there are two free modules $F$ and $F'$ such that
$$\ker\pi \oplus F \cong \ker \pi' \oplus F'$$
but I do not know how to prove this.
Some thoughts and attempts:
I have constructed a map $\ker \pi \to \ker \pi'$ as follows. Let $(f_1,...,f_k) \in \ker \pi$, i.e.
$$\sum_i f_im_i = 0$$
The $m_i$ are generated by the $n_j$. So we have a representation
$$m_i = \sum_jg_{ij}n_j$$
and thus we have
$$0 = \sum_i f_i \sum_j g_{ij}n_j = \sum_j \left(\sum_i f_i g_{ij}\right)n_j$$
and hence
$$\left(\sum_i f_i g_{i1}, ..., \sum_i f_i g_{ik'}\right) \in \ker \pi'$$
So, the map $\ker \pi \to \ker \pi '$ is well-defined. However, that is not enough. I also thought about using the five lemma with the two short exact sequences
$$0 \to \ker \pi \to F_0 \to M \to 0$$
and
$$0 \to \ker \pi' \to F_0' \to M \to 0$$
but this did not bring me any further. Any help is appreciated!
Update:
I played around a bit and tried to see whether the map $\ker \pi \to \ker \pi '$ could be made into an epimorphism in order to use the four-lemma on the right parts of the above sequences. It seems that it is not possible even if one would assume that $k \geq k'$ (i.e. the number of generators of $\ker \pi$ is geq than the number of generators from $\ker \pi'$). Perhaps I am overlooking something.

Your assumption is in general not true. You may assume that all modules in the short exact sequence are vector spaces and that $F_0,F_0'$ have different dimensions and this should give a counter example. If you want to know more about determining syzygies, you can take a look of Koszul complexes.

@Ubik I don't see how that is a counter example. Let $0 \to 0 \to K \to K \to 0$ and $0 \to K \to K^2 \to K \to 0$ be the two short exact sequences. Then $F_0 = K$ and $F'_0=K^2$ have different dimensions. But $\ker \pi' = K = 0 \oplus K = \ker \pi \oplus F$ where $F$ is the free module $K$. That works just fine I think.

@Ubik In Addition to that, the statement I want to prove is given in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_syzygy_theorem#Syzygies_(relations)
